# How to fix LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, visual-studio-2019, max-msp-jitter

I'm trying to compile a project that use OpenCV as static library with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.4.4.
I'm trying to fix this for several days without succes. 2486 Errors
Here is an exctract of the output log

```
1>libconcrt.lib(UMSSchedulerProxy.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
1>libconcrt.lib(UMSFreeVirtualProcessorRoot.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
1>libconcrt.lib(UMSThreadProxy.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
1>libconcrt.lib(UMSFreeThreadProxy.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
1>libconcrt.lib(UMSSchedulingContext.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
1>libconcrt.lib(UMSBackgroundPoller.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
1>libconcrt.lib(FreeThreadProxy.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
1>libconcrt.lib(TransmogrifiedPrimary.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
1>libconcrt.lib(Transmogrificator.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
1>libconcrt.lib(ThreadProxy.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
1>libconcrt.lib(location.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
1>libconcrt.lib(UMSThreadInternalContext.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
1>libconcrt.lib(VirtualProcessorRoot.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
1>libconcrt.lib(FreeVirtualProcessorRoot.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
1>libconcrt.lib(SchedulerProxy.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
1>libconcrt.lib(UMSWrapper.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
1>libconcrt.lib(WinRTWrapper.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
1>libconcrt.lib(ThreadProxyFactoryManager.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
1>libconcrt.lib(ScheduleGroupBase.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
1>libconcrt.lib(ExternalContextBase.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
1>libconcrt.lib(UMSThreadScheduler.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
1>libconcrt.lib(ExecutionResource.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
1>libconcrt.lib(Platform.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
1>libconcrt.lib(Exceptions.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
1>libconcrt.lib(ResourceManager.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
1>libconcrt.lib(InternalContextBase.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
1>libconcrt.lib(SchedulerBase.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
1>libconcrt.lib(Chores.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
1>libconcrt.lib(TaskCollection.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
1>libconcrt.lib(event.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
1>libconcrt.lib(CurrentScheduler.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
1>libconcrt.lib(rtlocks.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
1>libconcrt.lib(utils.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
1>libconcrt.lib(SchedulerPolicyBase.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
```

Comment: I think you have some type of conflict between the CRT used to compile opencv and the code you are compiling.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks, how I can verify the CRT ? I'm new to this.

Comment: Whatever runtime you selected when you built opencv as a static library you must select for your application